# How do you do a waitOn only on the first route in a session?

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I have a few publications that I want to subscribe to once at page load, and I want whatever the first route is to wait for those subs to be ready. I don't want the `waitOn` to run for future routes (as doing a global `waitOn` would do), because I'm using SubsManager, and the subs remain active for future routes.

For reference, here is what I'm doing currently:

```
Router.configure
  waitOn: ->
    sub_list = []

    for name in SUB_NAMES
      sub = home_subs.subscribe name
      sub_list.push sub

    sub_list
```

which has the benefit of the subs not being torn down between routes, but the function still runs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one solution. It doesn't use `waitOn` and doesn't have a `loadingTemplate`:

```
Router.configure autoStart: false
Tracker.autorun (c) ->
  if sub.ready()

    # don't know why defer is necessary
    _.defer ->
      Router.start()

    c.stop()
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that what you're doing is fine. SubsManager will know not to resubscribe when `waitOn` is called again. `waitOn` will (and should) be called each time the route changes so that the current route becomes dependent on the subscriptions being ready. If you want to avoid recreated `sub_list`, you can lazily create it and store it like this.

```
subscriptions = null

Router.configure
  waitOn: ->
    unless subscriptions?
      subscriptions = for name in SUB_NAMES
        home_subs.subscribe name
    subscriptions
```

Comment: Thanks, I get that resubscriptions won't happen, and your suggestion would help reduce the runtime of waitOn, but I'm looking for a way to not have it called at all – to have the first route wait on these subs, and not have a hook called thereafter.

Comment: Our `waitOn`s hardly ever get called. Have you profiled this? How do you know it's a problem?

Comment: Yep, devtools timeline flamechart